# Two functions execution at the same time

Tags: c

I'm doing a linear search on a sorted doubly linked list(holds bunch of integer ID). To do this, I'm using a temporary pointer assigned to head(holds the first value of dbl), and proceed to the next pointer until requested ID is found.

To cut short the time for searching, I can have another pointer which is assigned to tail(pointer holding the last value) and proceed backward along with the previous pointer

My implementation for linear search

```
struct node* find(long int value) { 
    struct node*temp = head, *temp1 = tail;
    while(temp->id < value && temp1->id > value){
        temp = temp->next;
        temp1 = temp1->prev;
    }
    if(temp->id == value)
        return temp;
    else if(temp1->id == value)
        return temp1;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Here temp1 proceeds to move backwards ,only after temp has moved forward

My Question:

Is there any way to move both forward(temp) and backward(temp1) pointers at the same time?

[I mean moving both the pointers parallely, to even decrease the time of comaprision]

KEY WORDS: Sorted doubly linked list, C language

Comment: Have you heard of multithreading?

Comment: No unless the language allows parallelism and doing parallel operations do not take longer that do the two steps in sequence.

Comment: @PSkocik I'm new to this concept. Would love to learn it

Comment: @jdweng I'm using c language

Comment: Why not have pointers to all nodes and check them all at the same time?

Comment: @Broman lmao what XD. It would be difficult for large number of inputs

Comment: In short, I would not recommend parallellism as my first resort to improve performance here. I would focus on making the data cache friendly.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using a linked list? If you need to be able to traverse the elements in sorted order, but have faster searching, insertion and deletion, you could use a self-balancing binary tree data structure, which would cut the search time down from O(N) to O(log N).

Comment: @IanAbbott AVL trees are superior to many other data structures in every operation. But I find it hard to understand and implement the code. Mind linking some good resources for self-balancing binary search trees? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your C implementation supports it, you could include the `<threads.h>` header and create new threads. This would allow you to use one thread to scan the list forward and another to scan the list backward. However, there are a number of issues with this, including:

- If you have so many nodes to check that creating an additional thread to scan them improves execution time significantly, then you have so many nodes that you could improve the searching of them by using a better structure than a doubly-linked list, such as trees or hashing.
- It is fairly easy to start a new thread, but it is harder to stop the threads in a sensible way. You would need to stop one thread when the other finds a result, and you would need to stop both threads when they meet each other in the list. This means adding more code for communication and coordination.
- Creating multiple threads can, in the right circumstances, reduce the “wall clock” execution time (how long it is until you get a result), but it does not reduce the resources consumed. Instead of using one processor for some amount of time, you would be using two processors for about the same total time. (“Total” meaning the sum of the execution times on each processor.)
- Some of the resources processors use is shared. For example, they both access the same main memory. Depending on exactly what resources your program requires, letting it use more processors might not help. If the bottleneck in your program is reading data from memory, the first processor is just waiting on memory anyway, and adding a second processor will just mean they are both waiting. That may be fine on a system where you are the only user and are not using it heavily (although there are questions of how much energy may be used doing it one way versus another). However, on a system where there are many processes running and the full CPU power is needed, it can be wasteful to use multiple processes to get a result sooner.
- Conversely, modern processors are very complicated and include some multiprocessing internally—a processor can compare some data at the same time it is asking for other data to be loaded from memory. Sometimes clever writing of code can take advantage of this multiprocessing to get multiple things done at once. For example, you could write code that alternately works forward in the list and backward, each one step at a time together in one loop, and the processor might execute this efficiently, comparing the data from one direction while loading data for the other direction.

It is not a bad idea to think about using parallel processing to speed up a program, but it is likely not the right approach for a simple scan of a doubly linked list. There are additional complications beyond those discussed above.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So if one function finds the address before the other, would it be difficult to stop the other thread?

Comment: @user8570772: Well, it is not difficult in the sense of writing code; we know how to do these things. But it means we have to make the computer do extra administrative work—communicate with a thread, call its exit routine, and so on. It is simply an extra cost that has to be factored into whether it is worth creating an extra thread or not.

Answer (score 2):

C language does not support execute multiple functions at the same time, as such. The only solution is multithreading. This, however, might open Pandora's box (how can one function knowing where the other function is working at?) which is solved using critical sections, mutexes, .... It's an interesting topic but you might do a lot of reading before you get something working.

Comment: C does support executing multiple functions at the same time, via threading. The `<threads.h>` header is standard, albeit optional.

Comment: Mutexes and interlocked operation take a lot of time and drop the processor cache. Thus multithreading can be of use only when you process separate chunks of data for a relatively long time and accumulate the result after it. Only then the synchronization overhead won't damper the performance.

Comment: @Dominique Can i have two search functions, one which starts searching from the front while the other which starts searching from last.[To achieve parallelism, whilst one function need not depend on the behaviour of other function which you have pointed]